# Jquery escaping characters ajax, convert back PHP

Tags: php, jquery

The data that is being sent via ajax is escaping the characters, how do i convert the characters back to normal html in PHP.

This is an example of the ajax response of the html table sent and echoed.

```
<td width=\"5%\" style=\"border-right:2px dashed #95989a\">�</td>
```

What php function do i use to revert the html table back to its original characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP function `stripcslashes` allows you to do this.

Have a look at [the documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)

Comment: What about `�` character?

Comment: That character seems to be more of an character encoding problem than escape characters being added.